# Which video player is better for .m3u8 format streaming videos in Android? VideoView or ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, android-videoview, exoplayer

I want to play a **.m3u8** streaming video with different **audio tracks** and different **subtitles**.

Here I have a question like which video player is better to play the .m3u8 streaming videos, with better performance.
I am Trying to solve this by using Native player, that is **VideoView** but at the time of working with audio-tracks and sub-Titles, I am facing problem with **videoView**.Here in the videoView I have to handle every thing through by coding ,there is no support form VideoView.

Can I achieve this with Exo player.
Can any body please suggest a best solution for audio tracks and subtitles support in the video player .

Comment: go with Exo player.

Comment: implementation 'cn.jzvd:jiaozivideoplayer:6.2.12' go with this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ExoPlayer is an application level media player for Android. It
>   provides an alternative to Android’s MediaPlayer API for playing audio
>   and video both locally and over the Internet. ExoPlayer supports
>   features not currently supported by Android’s MediaPlayer API,
>   including DASH and SmoothStreaming adaptive playbacks. Unlike the
>   MediaPlayer API, ExoPlayer is easy to customize and extend, and can be
>   updated through Play Store application updates.

From the [documentation](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/).

Exoplayer is super easy to use and it supports SmoothStreaming, in case your link provides multiple tracks, it'll adapt to the user connection, if the user has a poor connection it'll select the lower quality track, if the user has a good internet it'll select the high-quality track.

If playing audio or video is an important feature of your app, you should definetly use Exoplayer.

If you are not convinced yet, Exoplayer is used in Youtube, Google Music, Google Movies, Facebook, Whatsapp, Spotify, Twitter and 140,000 more. You can check in this [I/O lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAZn-J1I8Eg).

If you want to check a simple audio exoplayer sample you can see it [here](https://github.com/yusufcakmak/ExoPlayerSample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/yusufcakmak/exoplayersample/RadioPlayerActivity.java). And read [this article.](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-exoplayer-starters-guide-6350433f256c)

Answer (score 0):

as someone who has coped with same problem i think simplicity is more important than other factors. VideoView is so easy to use so go with it. 
tip: if you wanna make something like youtube style of playing you can use a Frame Layout on top of that and put buttons and imageviews and other stuff like that on it

Comment: But if I go through with VideoView , I am facing a problem to get the support for .mp3 video files adding and sub titles adding to the list. I have to handle thous things through coding @Namini40

Comment: Exoplayer is much simpler than you imagine. Few lines of code to implement incredible features. It supports playings ads, playings video or audio playlist, subtitles, playing several types of audios and smooth streaming, it supports mp3, mp4, dash, hls, wav and much more. You can easily customize the player layout and finally if you are going to deploy an app to google play. You definitely want to play audio as Spotify and the big ones do.